# Address 0x66 out of bounds

Tags: c

`closeTs` in `struct tic`  gives me an error -  `tsP=0x66 <Address 0x66 out of bounds>`. I try to fill it from oracle entry and if not, i try to assign a value. But I'm accessing it wrong in `fillFields`. Could someone give me a hint how can I fix it?
I have cutted a lot off, but imho it is enough to be able to get the problem:

```
typedef struct tic {
    char  closeTs[19];
    float close;
}tic, *ticP;

int buildQotHash(GTree* tree, char (*str)[3000])
{
    tic *t = malloc(sizeof(tic))  ;
    while (OCI_FetchNext(rs))
    {
        if (OCI_GetDate(rs, 4) != NULL) OCI_DateToText(OCI_GetDate(rs, 4), 
            "DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI", 19, t->closeTs );
    }
} 
void fillField(char* match, double* pf, char* tsP, char* message )
{

}
void fillFields(tic *t )
{
    fillField( CLOSEVORTAG, &t->close, t->closeTs,"CLOSEVORTAG,             " );
}

void processXML(char *start, char *stop, GTree* t)
{
    tic *ti  ; 
    if (triP != NULL && (key = g_tree_lookup (t, triP))!= NULL ) ti = (ticP)key;
    fillFields(ti);
}
```

Comment: I pity the next maintainer of the code who'll have to walk over a lot of broken glass to figure out what all the identifiers mean.

Comment: 0x666 would have been more interesting!

Answer (score 2):

I feel that the code you posted is quite incomplete, so I'm mostly guessing here...

In your function `processXML` what happens if the condition is not met?

```
void processXML(char *start, char *stop, GTree* t)
{
    tic *ti ; 
    if (triP != NULL && (key = g_tree_lookup (t, triP))!= NULL )
        ti = (ticP)key;
    //or else???
    fillFields(ti);
}
```

What happens is that `ti` is left uninitialized, and so any use of it will result in Undefined behavior. You are lucky and you are getting an *out of bounds* error.

What you probably want is:

```
void processXML(char *start, char *stop, GTree* t)
{
    //where is key declared, BTW???
    if (triP != NULL && (key = g_tree_lookup (t, triP))!= NULL )
    {
        tic *ti = (ticP)key;
        fillFields(ti);
    }
    // or else do nothing
}
```

That's why I always recommend to declare variables nearest to their use. This way `ti` is never uninitialized, and so your original mistake is impossible.

Comment: ti is initialized in buildQotHash. I'm getting "Address 0x66 out of bounds" while trying to use  t->closeTs.

Comment: @MaMu You seem to think `ti` is a global variable, but it clearly isn't since there's a local declaration inside `processXML()`.

Comment: But it is a pointer. And it is no problem to use it like that:   fillField( CLOSEVORTAG, &t->close, "CLOSEVORTAG" );

Comment: @MaMu: In the call to `fillField` you use `t`, which is a function argument. It is initialized with the values used when calling the function, that is, `ti` in processXML, which is a local variable that sometimes may be left unitialized and then used. Every time your program calls `processXML()` a new local `ti` variable is created, and every time it is created uninitialized.

Comment: @MaMu: I don't know what `buildQotHash` do, but certainly it does not initialize any local variable in `processXML()`.

Comment: which compiler do you use? In VC debug mode uninitialized memory will be filled with 0xCC so it's much easier to detect memory errors